# Bing for Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, bing

Is it possible to add an out-of-the-box Bing site search box to my SharePoint extranet and have it actually work?  My mind says no, since it can't possibly index my pages, right?  Just wanted to know your thoughts.

Comment: The "Bing" for SharePoint is called FAST…

Comment: If My answer helped you please marked it as a answer

Answer (score 2):

You can add bing search box and you would get results as well but only pages from your site which are allowed for anonymous access will be crawled by Bing. My question to you is this when share point already provides Such a wonderful search engine why do you need anything else for crawling of your internal content.

Comment: Client wishes...but I think a lack of knowledge that drove that choice.  I think we'll push back on that, after my initial thoughts were correct.  Thanks.